# How to avoid socket id change with socket.io?

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm currently trying to make a support application (like, to live chat with support) and I'm looking for a way to avoid the change of the socket id.

Here is my index.js code:

```js
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on("hello",()=>{
        socket.emit("hello",socket.id)
    })
})

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/client/index.html")
})

server.listen(1002)
```

And here is my client/index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Socket.io</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="socketid"></p>
    <script>
        const socket = io();
        socket.emit("hello")
        socket.on('hello',(message)=>{
            document.getElementById("socketid").innerHTML=message;
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot make socketid constant. Every time you reconnect or connect a new socket id will be given to you. Actually why do you want to make socketid constant?

Comment: If I make it content, I can still continue the chat even if the user changed the page he's on.

Comment: constant* sorry for the typo

Comment: Socket id will change so the better idea is to use cookies in your application. Like if the cookie is found then join the same room. You have to use rooms in your application

Comment: Good idea, I'll try that!